# Создать и удалить форму C#

Tags: c#, winforms, form, форма

Мне нужно создать приложение, которое в фоне выполняет различные действия, и при определённом условии создало форму, показало там что-то секунд на 5 и удалило форму и прога дальше осталась висеть в фоне выполнять всякое. Как такое сделать?

Зачем мне это: Прога в фоне постоянно проверяет определённое условие, если оно изменилось, необходимо запустить видео (media player, размещённый на форме). Как только видео закончилось проигрываться, прога должна исчезнуть.

На данный момент у меня реализовано так, что приложение создаётся и форма сразу становится невидимой, когда надо форма становится видимой. Мне нужно, чтобы, работая в фоне, прога занимала по минимуму места в оперативке, а с созданной скрытой формой она ест немало.

Форма в фоне висит невидимой и абсолютно пустой, в момент необходимости плеер создаётся и удаляется динамически и прога прячется. Почему до создания плеера прога вести 3 Мб в фоне, а после удаления плеера и скрытия формы ( по сути все ресурсы освободились ) прога вести 16-20 Мб?

Comment: Если уже что-то реализовано, почему бы вам этого не отобразить, что бы было понятно, откуда плясать?
По теме: По-хорошему, вам необходимо создавать форму в момент когда возникает необходимость её отобразить, а после всех манипуляций удалять (по таймеру, или как вам заблагорассудится)

Comment: Предположу, что на скрытой форме так и остаётся элемент с видео. Вы не пробовали делать динамические элементы в форме и удалять их перед скрытием формы? А также останавливать все таймеры, если используете. Тогда ваше приложение вообще ничего потреблять не будет, за исключением фонового потока.

Comment: Если всё выполняется в фоне, не передавайте управление из точки входа своей форме. Не пишите логику фона в событиях формы. Создавайте инстанс формы только в момент когда её надо показать, причём, делать это желательно в месте с ограниченным временем жизни. Попробуйте просто следовать этим правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: сделать консольное приложение, что в фоне даст мало памяти, подключить библиотеку System.Windows.Forms и клепать формы в консоли.
Еще вариант: сделать консольное приложение, сделать приложение форм, подключить в проект с консольным приложением формы (Ссылки - Добавить ссылку - Проекты) и открывать готовые формы из консоли. 
А если уж так важно кол-во ОЗУ (16 МБ для программы это очень мало в нынешних реалиях), то лучше смотреть не в сторону C#, а C или C++.